# summing up elements between two strings in list

Tags: python

I have  a list of `str` and `int` elements as given below

```
L = [1, "a", "b", 1, 2, 1, "d", 1, "e", 4, 5, "f", "g", 2]
```

I want to sum up numbers found between two string elements so resultant output is excpected like this.

```
[1, "a", "b", 4, "d", 1, "e", 9, "f", "g", 2]
```

I would like to solve this in a pythonic way. How this can be done?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? This is a fairly straightforward Python problem, and any AI will write the code for you, you don't need  StackOverflow for that (and it's not what StackOverflow is for). If you wrote something but need some help to get it to work, or understand why it is not working, include the code in your question and people will be happy to help.

Comment: I can do it with loops but I want more pythonic way of solving this, instead of multiline code

Comment: Show us your multiline code and explain what you think is wrong with it

Comment: Attempting to solve this with a list comprehension seems like it would produce a _less_ Pythonic solution; prefer understandability and maintainability over succinctness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a good use case for [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). We group the successive values by type (int/float or other), then we sum the numbers and add the others as is:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

L = [1, "a", "b", 1, 2, 1, "d", 1, "e", 4, 5, "f", "g", 2]

out = list(chain.from_iterable(([sum(g)] if k else g for k, g in
                                groupby(L, key=lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float))))))
```

Output:

```
[1, 'a', 'b', 4, 'd', 1, 'e', 9, 'f', 'g', 2]
```

Same approach combined with a loop:

```
out = []
for k, g in groupby(L, key=lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float))):
    if k:
        out.append(sum(g))
    else:
        out.extend(g)
```

And a more classical approach using only a loop:

```
out = []
add = False
for item in L:
    if isinstance(item, int):
        if add:
            out[-1] += item
        else:
            add = True
            out.append(item)
    else:
        add = False
        out.append(item)
```

Comment: Thanks .. I was looking for solution 1 without classical approach

Comment: @BharatSharma I understood that, but since answers are for everyone I though it would be better to demonstrate how it works by comparing to other approaches. In particular I think the second approach might be more explicit than the one-liner ;)

Answer (score 5):

An arguably cleaner approach would be to try adding the current item to the last one and defaulting to appending the item upon failure:

```
output = []
for i in L:
    try:
        output[-1] += +i
    except (TypeError, IndexError):
        output.append(i)
```

`output` becomes:

```
[1, 'a', 'b', 4, 'd', 1, 'e', 9, 'f', 'g', 2]
```

Comment: nice idea, I like it :)